# Remove unwanted padding around the background image from a button

Tags: android, android-button

This is the code used to generate the button

```
Button delBtn = new Button(activity);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
delBtn.setLayoutParams(params); 
delBtn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,R.drawable.ic_action_cancel, 0);
delBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(208, 0, 0));
```

Result Looks like this:

[image]

Whereas I expect:

[image]
`
What is it that I missed?

Comment: Does R.drawable.ic_action_cancel image have any padding or background?

Comment: Use TextView instand of Button. Button has default padding. we can not change it.

Comment: @ShineDown ic_action_cancel is standard resource from android. It is transparent and I think the padding it has is not this big

Comment: @Mansi: `TextView` did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As, suggested by Mansi (as comment, above), a simple `TextView` did the work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Imageview for this purpose as button has some padding value. And if the image has a background, you can make it transparent by:

```
imageButton.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: I had tried ImageButton; Will try once more. Thanks

Comment: Is it wrap_content that is causing problem for you. Can you try giving some value for width?

Comment: Hardcoding a width may not scale. Anyway, when I tried I found the padding keeps coming back.

Comment: Then try using ImageView

Comment: Infact, a simple TextView, as suggested by @Mansi did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

- Try Using ImagView instead of Button.
- Set your image in "src" attribute.
- Set background null/transperant.